# Scaling down Images in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am implementing an application in which an activity shows a image view with full screen. Now i have some images downloaded in application's file directory. I want to set image to image view in that activity for which i am scaling down the larger images. I am getting OutOfMemory error after 10 to 15 mins of using application. error is in decodeFile of BitmapFactory. Here is my code :

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String imagePath,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

}
```

**Right now i am giving reqHeight = 500 and reqWidth = 500**

This code is given in Android guidelines page. Is there anything i am missing, if so please help me out. I tried lots of things but not getting any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Change you int inSampleSize = 1; to int inSampleSize = 2 or 3 and test the application again, I hope this will solve your problem. I also suggest insted of this technique,try lazy loading for all you image dowanload by doing so there will be no bitmap and outOfMemoryError. Yo can have lazy loading  - https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
Bitmap resizedbitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(your_bitmap, width, height,
                        true);
```

it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a memory leak in your app if you are storing list of bitmaps returned by decodeSampledBitmapFromFile somewhere. Try to check for memory leak and also use [Bitmap.recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) to recycle bitmaps and help android free memory.